# JavaCV FFmpegFrameRecorder Video output reddish color

Tags: java, video, colors, ffmpeg, javacv

I am trying to make a video `.mp4` file out of a group of images using FFmpegFrameRecorder as a part of a bigger program, so I set up a test project in which I try to make a video out of 100 instances of the same frame at 25fps. The program seems to work. However, every time I run it the image seems to be reddish. As if a red filter had been applied to it.

Here's the code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("C:/Users/Diego/Desktop/tc-images/image0.jpg");
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(file);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    IplImage image = IplImage.createFrom(img); 
    FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("C:/Users/Diego/Desktop/tc-images/test.mp4",1920,1080); 
    try { 
    recorder.setVideoCodec(13);
    recorder.setFormat("mp4");
    recorder.setPixelFormat(0);
    recorder.setFrameRate(25);
    recorder.start(); 
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++){ 
    recorder.record(image); 
    } 
    recorder.stop(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e){ 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
```

I'd appreciate it if anybody told me what's wrong. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a similar problem.. It seems that my problem was not setting the pixelFormat correctly. I eventually set it to

```
org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32_1
```

and it now exports properly!

Actually from what I see in my code, I never call `recorder.setPixelFormat();`

Instead, I set the pixel format while recording like this:

```
recorder.record(image,org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32_1);
```

If that does not work I would try the various formats [at the source code of the avutil class](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/avutil.html)!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked perfectly. It's worth to note though that it only worked when I set the pixel format the same way you said you did instead of the way I was doing so.

Comment: Quick follow-up question, is there any way you know of to add an audio file to the output video?